# Need a fingerprint attendance management software

Tags: windows-7, time-management

I have a network-based fingerprint attendance system and I'm searching for a free management software. Device model is ZEM500 and algorithm version is "VX 9.0". It uses Web 3.0 as its web interface.

Edit: The OS is Windows 7. They want to add and remove employees, extract report and statistics for the attendance. You can say these are the minimum. I'll update with more requirements if needed

P.S.: Sorry if the tag is not related, I could not find one.

Comment: @Izzy I updated the question. I'll update with more requirements if needed

Comment: A business friend suggested that we develop something similar. I searched AliBaba and found the fingerprint scanner plus some very good software for about US $25. We decided not to go up against that. Is there any chance that you could swap out your existing system for a cheap off-the-shelf solution if it fits your needs?

Comment: Something like this http://www.everychina.com/p-z52ef6c3-103532615-ko-s200-rfid-card-time-attendance-with-software-and-sdk-api.html  which is ZEM500 based(although it does not mention "VX 9.0"). It says that it has an SDK/API. Or, why not contact the manufacturer? Btw, this is the one that I decided not to compete against - and it has  Telnet interface, which should be helpful ... http://blog.infobytesec.com/2014/07/perverting-embedded-devices-zksoftware_2920.html

Comment: In case you don't know, an Application Programming Interface (API) means that you can write your own software to interact with it, or pay someone else to, [Fiverr](https://www.fiverr.com/) or similar), or search GitHub, SourceForge, etc for matching software.